# Detect where custom post type is declared

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

In a plugin that I'm developing I'd like to be able to display a list of all custom post types currently enabled.  Is there any way to detect where a post type has been initiated?  For example, if it was created by a plugin, is there a way to detect that and then report the plugin or file where it was initiated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook into `registered_post_type` and store the data from [`debug_backtrace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php). The third entry should be the calling plugin.

### Sample code

```
add_action( 'registered_post_type', 'track_post_types', 10, 2);

function track_post_types( $post_type = NULL, $args = array() )
{
    static $tracked = array();

    if ( 'shutdown' === current_filter() )
    {
        print '<pre>$tracked = ' . esc_html( var_export( $tracked, TRUE ) ) . '</pre>';
        return;
    }

    if ( $args->_builtin )
        return;

    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    $tracked[ $post_type ] = $backtrace[3];

    add_action( 'shutdown', __FUNCTION__ );
}
```

### Sample output

```
  array (
    'file' => 'F:\\Dropbox\\wp-content\\plugins\\t5-cpt-tester\\t5-cpt-tester.php',
    'line' => 45,
    'function' => 'register_post_type',
    'args' => 
    array (
      0 => 'project',
      1 => 
      array (
        'can_export' => true,
        'description' => '',
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'labels' => 
        array (
          'add_new' => 'Add new',
          'add_new_item' => 'Add new project',
          'all_items' => 'All projects',
          'edit_item' => 'Edit project',
          'name' => 'Projects',
          'name_admin_bar' => 'Project',
          'new_item' => 'New project',
          'not_found' => 'No projects found.',
          'not_found_in_trash' => 'No projects in trash.',
          'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent project:',
          'search_items' => 'Search projects',
          'singular_name' => 'Project',
          'view_item' => 'View project',
        ),
        'menu_icon' => NULL,
        'menu_position' => NULL,
        'permalink_epmask' => 1,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => 'project',
        'rewrite' => 
        array (
          'slug' => 'project',
          'with_front' => false,
        ),
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'supports' => 
        array (
          0 => 'author',
          1 => 'comments',
          2 => 'editor',
          3 => 'excerpt',
          4 => 'revisions',
          5 => 'thumbnail',
          6 => 'title',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Amazing!  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Side note: This works just as well when the post type is created via a theme.